# Angstrom OpenEmbedded Kernel freeze when booting on original BeagleBoard

Tags: linux, kernel, beagleboard, angstrom-linux, openembedded

I am trying to get an original BeagleBoard (revC4) to boot a Angstrom OpenEmbedded image. Using instructions found here:

http://elinux.org/BeagleBoardAndOpenEmbeddedGit

and:

http://www.angstrom-distribution.org/building-angstrom

I have followed everything but the program freeze with message booting the kernel.

## Output:

```
Texas Instruments X-Loader 1.4.2 (Feb 19 2009 - 12:01:24)
Reading boot sector
Loading u-boot.bin from mmc


U-Boot 2009.11 (Feb 23 2010 - 15:33:48)

OMAP3530-GP ES3.1, CPU-OPP2 L3-165MHz
OMAP3 Beagle board + LPDDR/NAND
I2C:   ready
DRAM:  256 MB
NAND:  256 MiB
In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Board revision C4
Die ID #40a8000400000000040365fa1301c014
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 
mmc1 is available
reading boot.scr

** Unable to read "boot.scr" from mmc 0:1 **
reading uImage

4335440 bytes read
Booting from mmc ...
 Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 82000000 ...
   Image Name:   Linux-3.2.28
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    4335376 Bytes =  4.1 MB
   Load Address: 80008000
   Entry Point:  80008000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK
OK

Starting kernel ...

Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel.
```

I have tried both `ttyS2` and `ttyO2` in the bootargs without difference and have also upgraded both the xLoader and uBoot.

My end goal is to run a rudimentary ROS (Robot Operating System) and the BeagleBoard.

Any help would truly be appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to say what is going on exactly judging from the output you provided. You can try to use earlyprintk to debug this issue. Add `earlyprintk` to kernel cmdline (in u-boot) and also rebuild kernel with earlyprintk config options enabled. It should give you more consistent kernel output, so you can see what causes kernel stuck.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I am unsure how to rebuild the kernel with earlyprintk. I am using the Angstrom image builder. I am also unsure how to add the line to u-boot? Sorry I am fairly new at this.

Comment: Enter u-boot shell, pressing Enter just after reset. Kernel cmdline is stored in "bootargs" variable. You can observe using `print bootargs`. To add `earlyprintk` to this variable use `setenv bootargs $bootargs earlyprintk`. As for kernel I'm not sure, because you are using wrapper (image builder), but it always boils down to next: you need to fix your defconfig file so that it has `CONFIG_DEBUG_LL=y`, `CONFIG_DEBUG_KERNEL=y` and `CONFIG_EARLY_PRINTK=y`. It should be done using `make ARCH=arm menuconfig` command (after `.config` file generated from your defconfig).

Comment: See [this link](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Kernel_-_Common_Problems_Booting_Linux) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you ever got past this, but as I have recently been trying to get a Beagleboard up and running again, I'll put an answer here for the sake of anyone else trying to get things working.

TLDR version: Use Angstrom v2013.6 and hold the user button as you boot (or zero out the NAND flash) for the easiest solution that just works. See below for more details.

First of all, the place you're stuck at here is due to the u-boot flashed into NAND being out-of-date for a recent version of Angstrom. Simple fix is to hold down the user button when booting, which will bypass NAND and boot straight from the SD card, which presumably has the version of u-boot you just built. You can then stop the boot and either zero out the NAND or flash the current MLO and u-boot into it.

After that, you'll run into some more issues if you're using an image based on systemd. The meta-ti layer controls the basic parameters for the 'beagleboard' configuration and has its virtual/kernel provider set to linux-mainline, which is also in the meta-ti layer. At some point there was a new recipe version added for it which builds a 3.14 kernel, but the kernel configuration isn't suitable for systemd and the system will hang shortly after booting.

The good news is that Angstrom v2013.06 predates the 3.14 kernel change in meta-ti, and I was able to get that running just fine. I am trying to get a more recent Angstrom working with the 3.2 kernel that works with v2013.6, but I haven't had any luck yet.